# Translate Magento Shop Categories

Tags: magento, localization, internationalization, magento-1.9

I want to translate categories in magento but I didn't found any way but only to add products multiple times and set different store view but that is really very time consuming if I have lots of categories and lots of site views.

Any short way to translate categories?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that one is one of these things that can be done without extensions but are not intuitive. I had to check a video from youtube to get to the solution, which is:

- Go to Catalog->Manage categories.
- Select the category you want to translate. I am assuming that this category applies to the whole store, all store views included.
- Then at the top left box select the store view that you want to display the category in a different language, i.e. "English".
- Now the general information tab of the category shows checkboxes with the option "Use default value". Uncheck the checkbox for the field "Name" and change the name for the translated text.
- Save category.

In case you find difficult to follow my instructions check this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VppfnO14jfE